# Freeze Screen updating Access?

Tags: ms-access

How to stop screen updating in access ?

For Each Button "me.painting = false "didn't work

Note :- the form have a lot of Buttons :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Application.Echo False
' complicated code
Application.Echo True
```

Be sure that `Application.Echo True` is always reached - if it is skipped e.g. due to a runtime error, your users will have to kill Access via Task Manager.

Comment: Buttons dont Have event Procedure it have Macro

Comment: Only I asked to disable all screen updating when I click the button